# Display viewModel list where the id in the list is equal to the selected id by user

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, vb.net

I am trying to create an MVC application in vb.net that will display an issue if its comments.  The issue is in one table called IssueTable and has a one-to-many relationship with the commentsTable.
I am having trouble displaying information from a list of comments that are on one specific issue.

Here is the viewModel.

```
Public Class IssueCommentsViewModel
    Public Issues As IssueTable
    Public Comments As List(Of CommentTable)
End Class
```

I am displaying it in the view like this:

```
@Model.Issues.IssueKey

@For Each comment In Model.Comments
    @comment.CommentBody
Next
```

The problem I am having lies in the controller:

```
Dim tModel = New IssueTracker.IssueCommentsViewModel()
tModel.Issues = dbServer.IssueTables.Find(id)
tModel.Comments = dbServer.CommentTables.ToList().Where(Function(x) x.IssueID = id)
```

I get an error because the tModel.Comments is a list and I am equaling it to a Table.  How can I make the viewModel.CommentList (tModel.Comments) equal to a populated list of comments where the issueID is equal to the selected id variable?

Comment: You didn't say what the error is, but did you try reordering the query - `dbServer.CommentTables.Where(Function(x) x.IssueID = id).ToList()`?

Comment: yes that worked exactly thanks if you add it as an answer i will accepted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The order of your LINQ query will result in an `IEnumerable(Of CommentTable)`, which is not assignable to a `List(Of CommentTable)`.  If you reorder your query as shown, the assignment should work:

```
tModel.Comments = dbServer.CommentTables.Where(Function(x) x.IssueID = id).ToList()
```